# ReactJs Accordion Automatic Close Mechanism

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I'm currently working on an accordion component in react version 16.3.2, that receives props from another component and displays the accordion accordingly. Unfortunately I cannot use hooks.

This works pretty smoothly, what I want to implement now is a way so that only one accordion can be opened at the same time on the same page. So, once you open one accordion (while another is already opened) it should automatically close the already opened one.

I have an Id (string which describes the current section, e.g 'contact', 'info', etc.) and the state of an accordion gets saved in the state (set to true when you toggle the accordion).
I'm not quite sure on how I could implement this mechanism and am looking for tips on how I could solve this in a smart way. Any pointers?

example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-accordion-automatic-close-mechanism-6dys1
(I didn't add all of the styling, animations since this is more about functionality)

Comment: use a function to close all accordions and call it on every accordion click!

Comment: @BhavyaSingh I'm not sure how I can distinguish it, how can I close only the accordion clicked on? I've tried using event listener but it doesn't seem to work with what I have here

Comment: Kindly make this one as you expected or working will update the missing part https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-accordion-automatic-close-mechanism-8zrfe

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you very much, I've updated the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-accordion-automatic-close-mechanism-6dys1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find solution for your problem in the following codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-accordion-automatic-close-mechanism-yejc0

Change prop names as it fits your code base, but the logic is solid

Comment: I think I might have to make it work so that it can use the string as an id instead of the number, since I don't wanna set a number for every accordion. This is definitely the right direction, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you are right. If this was helpful or if it solved your problem, could you mark my response as resolved?

Comment: I will as soon as I can fix it. Unfortunately I can't use 'useState', my project uses react 16.3.2 and due to other modules I cannot upgrade just yet.

Comment: I have fixed my codesandbox to not to use useState but class syntax

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, using the state hook in the App component

```
export default function App() {
  const items = [
    { id: 1, title: 'First Accordion', content: 'Hello' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Click me', content: 'Hello 2' },
    { id: 3, title: 'Third Accordion Accordion', content: 'Hello 3' },
  ]

  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(1)

  const handleClick = id => {
    setSelectedItem(id)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map(x => {
        return (
          <Accordion 
            key={x.id} 
            id={x.id}
            title={x.title} 
            open={x.id === selectedItem}
           onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <p>{x.title}</p>
          </Accordion>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then your accordion component is a bit simpler

```
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  accToggle() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.id);
  }

  sectionClasses() {
    let classes = "accordion";
    classes += this.props.open ? " sec-on" : "";
    classes += "sec-underway";

    return classes.trim();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className={this.sectionClasses()} id={this.props.id}>
        <div className="acc-title" onClick={this.accToggle.bind(this)}>
          <h3 className="acc-text">{this.props.title}</h3>
          <div className="acc-nav">
            <span className="acc-toggle" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="acc-content">{this.props.children}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

Accordion.defaultProps = {
  open: false
};

Accordion.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.any,
  onFocus: PropTypes.func,
  progress: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.bool
  ]),
  title: PropTypes.string,
  open: PropTypes.bool
};

export default Accordion;
```

The accordion calls a function on the app component, which updates the state and the display logic is passed down in the props